# Create an XML file using Javascript or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, xmldom

I have a `XM`L file as follows:

```
<bracelets>
     <photo filename="b1.jpg" thumbnail="a1.jpg" description="aa" />
     <photo filename="b2.jpg" thumbnail="a2.jpg" description="aa" />
     <photo filename="b3.jpg" thumbnail="a3.jpg" description="aa" />
     <photo filename="b4.jpg" thumbnail="a4.jpg" description="aa" />
</bracelets>
```

I want to fetch all image names into a `.php` page.

I am using this now.

```
$bracelets = simplexml_load_file($bracelets_xml);
        x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('photo')[0].attributes;
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            document.write(x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        }​
```

But currently I am only able to fetch one image.

How can I fetch all images instead?

Comment: Do you understand the code you have written? I think you should start with figuring out what each line does, because that will instantly answer your question.

Comment: Yeah, that `[0]` is pretty much going to limit it to only the first one.

Comment: @Tomalak I have got the correct answer from Anthony and edited the question too. But I cant ask anymore question from Stackoverflow because of bad voting the question they blocked me, Please help me to make it work, Thank you n advence..

Comment: @Wazan Please ask for support on http://meta.stackoverflow.com - I am just a normal user and can't help you with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If PHP is an option, have you looked at [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) yet?

In your case:

```
    $bracelets_xml = <<<XML
    <bracelets>
            <photo filename="b1.jpg" thumbnail="a1.jpg" description="aa" />
            <photo filename="b2.jpg" thumbnail="a2.jpg" description="aa" />
            <photo filename="b3.jpg" thumbnail="a3.jpg" description="aa" />
            <photo filename="b4.jpg" thumbnail="a4.jpg" description="aa" />
    </bracelets>
XML;
    
$bracelets = new SimpleXMLElement($bracelets_xml);
    
foreach($bracelets -> photo as $photo) {
    $counter++;
    echo "Photo " . $counter . ":\r\n";
    echo "Filename : " . $photo['filename'] . "\r\n";
    echo "Thumbnail : " . $photo['thumbnail']. "\r\n";
    echo "Description : " . $photo['description']. "\r\n";
}
```

Obviously the output above isn't what you want, but you could output it however you want depending on the context.

Comment: I checked , Im geting the looping Problem

Comment: You're getting what looping problem? I could have miswritten something. Are you getting an error?

Comment: Actually, I just copied and pasted my own code and your sample xml and it works fine.  What looping problem?

Comment: $yourxmlstring = simplexml_load_file("bracelets/flashmo_038_thumbnails.xml");
$bracelets = new SimpleXMLElement($yourxmlstring);

foreach($bracelets -> photo as $photo) {
   echo $photo['filename'];
   echo $photo['thumbnail'];
   echo $photo['description'];
}

?>

Comment: I tidied up the output so it should be clearer whether it's working or not. Which it is.

Comment: Ahhh. I see. using simple_xml_load_file creates the SimpleXMLElement automatically, so just change your code to: `$bracelets = simplexml_load_file("bracelets/flashmo_038_thumbnails.xml");` and go from there.

Comment: im geting an error
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in C:\xampp\htdocs\unixpo\gallery.php:82 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\unixpo\gallery.php(82): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\unixpo\gallery.php on line 82

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all the elements returned by `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('photo')`.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('photo')[0].attributes;
```

Gets the first photo. Then you do things with it.

Change that to a for loop like the one you have for looping over the attributes.